# Anyone know why skype4py's IsRunning method returns False regardless of whether or not Skype is actually running?

Tags: python, skype4py

I'm guessing this may be a bug, if so, it's my first time encountering a bug "in the wild" so to speak. So, I'm not entirely sure what to do.

#### The Documentation:

```
Properties:
    IsRunning
    Tells if Skype client is running.
```

#### My Code:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    skype = Skype4Py.Skype()
    print skype.Client.IsRunning
```

It print false even when Skype is, in fact, running. Any ideas...?

Comment: Try calling skype.Attach() first.

Comment: @Deusdies Tried that, but still no luck. Plus, I'm trying to avoid calling Attach() until I verify that Skype is actually running. Calling it when Skype is not running causes the program to hang until it times out.

Comment: Sounds like a fairly buggy script. I've just downloaded it on my computer and I can confirm that I have the same issue, even after calling `Attach()`. You should however know that Skype is not exactly outside-software friendly, I fear.

Comment: Please report this issue at https://github.com/awahlig/skype4py/issues

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem and found this fix at

https://github.com/awahlig/skype4py/issues/11

Just changing the following line in **C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\Skype4Py\api\windows.py**

```
windll.user32.FindWindowA('tSkMainForm.UnicodeClass', None))
```

to

```
windll.user32.FindWindowA('tSkMainForm', None))
```

worked for me. Hope it helps someone in the future